# Understanding when a function in assembly is either void or int

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, att

So I have the following code in assembly:

[image]

I know that the parameters for the function are two (x and y or any letter). The problem is that I don't know how to see from the assembly code whether the function is returning anything since it only says `ret`. Would this function be considered void or int? Any explanation for understanding would be well appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and change the picture of source code into text.

Comment: If the function is not void, then the value being returned seems like it's of dubious value.  I mean it's just the value from the first parameter.  Why would the function need to return that, especially since it's unmodified?  More importantly: Why do you need to know whether it's void/int?  If you are calling the function from C, you can declare it as either and have it compile/run.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 5):

Both is possible.  You cannot in general tell if a value is to be returned or not just form looking at the code of the function.  For more certainty, look for functions that call this function and check if these functions inspect the return value.  If any of them does, there is a return value.  If not, there is likely no return value.

Answer (score 3):

The return value is passed in the register eax / rax, if needed.

Since that register is modified, first reading from the variable `x`, then adding to the other variable, both cases are possible. In the `void` case, the `eax` register can contain any value, not limited to `*x`.

```
void f(int *x, int *y) {
    *y += *x;
}

int g(int *x, int *y) {
    int z = *x;
    *y += z;
    return z;
}
```

As a counter-example,

```
void h(int x, int *y) { *y += x; }

add %edi, (%rsi)
ret
```

would clearly have `void` as the only possible signature.

A clear indicator of `int` return value OTOH is when there are no side effects (such as stores) after the last modification of `eax/rax` - no reasonable optimizing compiler would produce such a code, however a reasonable obfuscating compiler possibly would.

Comment: The example in the question has an `add`, not `mov` like your examples.

Comment: You have the parameters backwards. rdi is the first parameter.

Comment: but return value can be returned in a different register in functions using custom calling conventions, like the handwritten ones or optimized internal functions emitted from optimizing compilers

Answer (score 2):

In high-level languages there is generally a formal notion of a function.  Functions have features like:

- A signature — describing parameters & return value type

  Many languages also allow optional parameters (usually with default values supplied if the caller doesn't specify)

  A number of languages allow variable parameters, usually after fixed parameters
- Either a return value type or void — but not both
- Limited to a single entry point
- Multiple possible return points — that must all return the same type

Most of the above amounts to restrictions/limitations that tell us what we cannot do, and these constraints allow the language implementations to catch errors at build time, while also preventing certain chaos (hard to find bugs) at runtime.

These formalizations were, in part, developed after years of experience with assembly language, which is lacking these formalizations, and hence these restrictions/limitations.

In assembly code, there is no formalization of the notion of function.  Thus, there are fewer rules to break, you can:

- Have multiple entry points
- Have different signatures for the same function
- Return different types of values (including void) from different return spots
- Jump from one function to another without invoking the function properly
- etc..

---

> Would this function be considered void or int?

We don't actually know for certain, as assembly, especially disassembly doesn't offer that information.

The `%eax` register is allowed to be used as a temporary, so leaving a value there doesn't tell us much.  The value in `%eax` is used by the next instruction, so from that we cannot infer whether `%eax` is a return value or not.  If the `mov` were not followed by the `add` then that `mov` would be unnecessary/useless waste for a void function, which would tip the argument towards return value rather than void return.

We can also reason that the function *always* places a "useful" value in `%eax` — which is to say, it puts a return value into `%eax` on every code path that returns.  However, given how simple the function is, this doesn't mean much.

A `ret` alone doesn't tell us anything about the return type.

> I know that the parameters for the function are two (x and y or any letter)

The parameters registers are being used as 8-byte pointers to 4-byte items that add, presumably `int` or `unsigned int`, meaning the parameters are `int *` or `unsigned int *` (or a mix of the two!).

As `fuz` says, more information can be gleaned by looking at the caller to see whether they use the return value, and if they do (and the code is known to be correct) then the function returns a value.  However, if they don't, that isn't a guarantee that the function is `void` since a caller can choose to ignore a return value.  That's why it is said that if no caller uses the return value, it is *likely* `void`.

Comment: *meaning the parameters are* - I might say that the first parameter is a `const int *`.